# Selecting popwindow in Selenium using Index

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Is there any possibility of selecting windows based on Index as done in Iframes?

> Selects a frame within the current
>   window. (You may invoke this command
>   multiple times to select nested
>   frames.) To select the parent frame,
>   use "relative=parent" as a locator; to
>   select the top frame, use
>   "relative=top". You can also select a
>   frame by its 0-based index number;
>   select the first frame with "index=0",
>   or the third frame with "index=2".

When Selenium can get all window titles or names, is it possible to write like this?

```
selectWindow(getAllWindowsNames[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium [javadoc](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/) says that `selectWindow` requires javascript window ID. Hence window names won't work. 
Have you seen another similar method `getAllWindowIds()`? You can use that method to select it using index like `selectWindow(getAllWindowIds()[1])` :)

Hope this helps